# Convention for naming browser cookies

Tags: language-agnostic, cookies, session-cookies

I notice that cookies set by sites all have the following names

```
__utma, __utmb, __utmc, __utmz
```

Is this a convention? Or is it the default values created by some server side language? Is there a specific meaning to these? Are these expected? Can some one explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**These are Google Analytics Cookies**

**The __utma Cookie:**

This cookie is what’s called a “persistent” cookie, as in, it never expires (technically, it does expire…in the year 2038…but for the sake of explanation, let’s pretend that it never expires, ever). This cookie keeps track of the number of times a visitor has been to the site pertaining to the cookie, when their first visit was, and when their last visit occurred. Google Analytics uses the information from this cookie to calculate things like Days and Visits to purchase.

**The __utmb and __utmc Cookies:**

The B and C cookies are brothers, working together to calculate how long a visit takes. __utmb takes a timestamp of the exact moment in time when a visitor enters a site, while __utmc takes a timestamp of the exact moment in time when a visitor leaves a site. __utmb expires at the end of the session. __utmc waits 30 minutes, and then it expires. You see, __utmc has no way of knowing when a user closes their browser or leaves a website, so it waits 30 minutes for another pageview to happen, and if it doesn’t, it expires.

**The __utmz Cookie:**

Mr. __utmz keeps track of where the visitor came from, what search engine you used, what link you clicked on, what keyword you used, and where they were in the world when you accessed a website. It expires in 15,768,000 seconds – or, in 6 months. This cookie is how Google Analytics knows to whom and to what source / medium / keyword to assign the credit for a Goal Conversion or an Ecommerce Transaction. __utmz also lets you edit its length with a simple customization to the Google Analytics Tracking code.

**The __utmv Cookie:**

If you are making use of the user-defined report in Google Analytics, and have coded something on your site for some custom segmentation, the __utmv cookie gets set on the person’s computer, so that Google Analytics knows how to classify that visitor. The __utmv cookie is also a persistent, lifetime cookie.

taken from GA article:
 `http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/from-__utma-to-__utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense why I see almost every web site setting these cookies. I thought its some convention I was not aware of :)

Comment: "it never expires" - hmm, I think that might be a bit out of date. I have __utma cookies (from SO, actually) that expire in 2012 and 2013. Which is still very nearly as good as never from the POV of tracking users, since for the vast majority of sites, the vast majority of their repeat visitors visit more often than once every couple of years. Minor difference in practice, since anyone who actively cares about this stuff will be deleting the cookies way more frequently than their expiration date, whether it's 2038 or 2013.