# __utma, __utmb, __utmz Cookies - How can my website set these cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I found the following cookies on my website:

- __utma
- __utmb
- __utmz

In an internet research I read now that they are set by Google Analytics.
I did not use Google Analytics.
How can my website set these cookies?

Edit 
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by 'cookies on my website'? Are you sure they are not sitting in your browser, created by a previous (Google Analytics enabled) site you visited?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately I can not reproduce it now. But I have seen the cookies when calling my website. I added a picture to the question to explain this better.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Are you using any 3rd party code at all within your website? Any of that could potentially be using GA.

Comment: If you are seeing these cookies (legacy GA library used to set these) attached to your domain in your browser this means that once your browser has received these cookies from your website. It could be because once there was GA installed on a website, your browser is using plugin which is using GA, etc..

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985909/convention-for-naming-browser-cookies/5985943

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.  Perhaps there was a thiRd party extension in the past. 
In the last time I did not see that cookie again.